# change a navigation tabs to carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

We have a navigation tab with each tab having a grid of images [image].

With change in screen size, we want to be able to remove all the tabs but the first one. And display the images in first tab in a carousel view.

[image]

I tried using the addClass and removeClass option, buts its getting super complicated and not very efficient. I feel there should be a easier way to manage this.

Comment: I don't understand you can do this with a simple hidden-xs class on the tab you want to hide!

Comment: I will have to copy the image content of the grid in another div. one for tab section and one for carousel. Anyway to achieve that by maintaining same div.

Answer (score 0):

Here a little code that will maybe help you:

```js
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 320) {
    function mySlider(){
        // Your slider code here
    }
    mySLider();
}
```

```css
ul li { width:33%; border-right:1px solid red;border-bottom:1px solid red; background:blue; color: white; height:150px; text-align:center; float:left; display:inline-block;}

ul li:nth-child(3n){
border-right:0;
}

@media (max-width:320px){
.slider{width:320px;}
.sliderOverflow{
    width:500000px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
ul li {
    width:320px;
} 
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div class="sliderOverflow">
    <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>
        </div>
</div>
```